# modal popup code placement

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Is is possible to separate the actual popup message from the page that it is called from?  The examples I have found contain the call to the popup.js file and the div containing the message on the same page.

I'd like to be able to maintain a separate page for the message, but am having trouble implementing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ajax to load the content into the modal.  Just use the callback to trigger the showing of the modal after the content is loaded.

```
$('#modal-content').load('path/to/content.html', function() {
    $('#modal').show();
}
```

Where `modal-content` is the div you wish to place the content in, and where `modal` is the modal wrap you wish to show.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed. How do I modify the events, for example the close button no longer works - $("#closePopup").click(function(){disablePopup();});

Comment: I would assume you would use `$('#modal').hide();`

Comment: It seems that the click event isn't recognized after setting the page to an included file.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where you're placing the js, but use .live('click', function()... Instead of .click for the cancel.

Answer (score 0):

You could open a separate browser window for your pop-up. I haven't tried to make one window modal over another but you may be able to do so in using the the focus/blur events. Depending on how big your user audience is you may run into trouble with pop-up blockers however.  Probably not a good option on the open web.

Answer (score 0):

To take johndavidjohn's answer one step further.... you can use this code to actually add the modal div to the body on the fly, so you don't need to include it.

```
if (('#modal-content').length() == 0)
    $('body').append('<div class="modal" id="modal-content"></div>');

$('#modal-content').load('path/to/content.html', function() {
    $('#modal').show();
}
```